# Enter a valid date/time in Django Forms

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Anytime I try to input datetime into my form, it always says *Enter a valid date/time*
I tried different datetime formats; the one i speified and the default ones, they all did not work.
I have tried different solutions on Stack Overflow, but they all do not seem to work.
The field I have this issue with is *due_date*

NOTE: I didn't show any imports

Also, i need recommendations for nice datetime pickers. All the ones I tried didn't work for some reason or the other.

**views.py:**

```
@login_required
def task_create(request):
    data = dict()
#, data=request.POST
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TaskForm(request.user, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            data['form_is_valid'] = True
        else:
            data['form_is_valid'] = False
    else:
        form = TaskForm(request.user)

    context = {'form': form}
    data['html_form'] = render_to_string('partial_task_create.html',
        context,
        request=request
    )
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

**forms.py:**

```
class TaskForm(ModelForm):

    due_date = forms.DateTimeField(input_formats=['%I:%M %p %d-%b-%Y'])    
    parent = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Task.objects.all(), empty_label="---None---", required=False)
    #widget=DateTimePickerInput(format='%I:%M %p %d-%m-%Y')

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ['task_title', 'task_description', 'due_date', 'is_completed', 'categories', 'parent']   
        widgets = {
             #'due_date': DateTimeInput()
        }     

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):        
        super(TaskForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['categories'].queryset = Categories.objects.filter(Q(user_id__isnull=True) | Q(user_id=user.id))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to set the widget attribute on the due_date form field to match the input formats.
Something like:

```
due_date = forms.DateTimeField(input_formats=['%I:%M %p %d-%b-%Y'],
             widget = forms.DateTimeInput(
                 attrs={'type': 'datetime-local'},
                 format='%I:%M %p %d-%b-%Y'))
```

For datetime pickers, take a look at https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker

Comment: After I tried this, it changed the element on the page from a TextField to a DateTime field (something of the form, mm/dd/yyyy --:-- --) that allows a dropdown for only the Date... After i pick a date and time, it still says the same thing, Enter a valid date/time

Comment: Maybe try to change your input formats to one of these in the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS